# Is the CLI optimized for throughput?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-cli

Would the very latest Azure CLI chunk big files and do parallel uploads for max. throughput by default, sending in a signal about all the chunks uploaded before or after downloading like in the test case below described?

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/high-throughput-with-azure-blob-storage/

(Context: This relates to the news about high-performance BlobStorage.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! :)

AFAIK this is currently unsupported via CLI.

As per this -> https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/7616 open GitHub issue, approach of invoking AzCopy through CLI is on-going. Check the same link for further updates.

If you have question of why AzCopy then please refer this -> [Azure CLI : bash script to upload files in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45012750/azure-cli-bash-script-to-upload-files-in-parallel) thread which talks about accomplishing the requirement with AzCopy approach.

Other related references:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-upload-batch

https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-scalable-app-upload-files?view=azure-java-stable

Hope this helps!! Cheers!! :)

Note: If you think your question has been answered then please 'accept' it, if just helped then click "This answer is useful" and provide an up vote. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Comment: Would be great to see this implemented per default with the next CLI versions: "If you have question of why AzCopy then please refer this -> Azure CLI : bash script to upload files in parallel thread which talks about accomplishing the requirement with AzCopy approach." - At least as an optional flag. And could make a lot of sense with high-throughput storage.